# How to alter styling declared in global style.scss from a child component css and scope it only for that component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components, ng-deep

I have declared some css styling in global style.css file which is src/style.css in my angular project. In one of my component I want to alter some styling and scope it only for that component. Currently, I can able to do that by using ::ng-deep, but, problem is, while I am changing global style from my child component using ::ng-deep it also alter the styling in global.scss as a result rest of my component also affecting for this. So what I want is, when I am changing this global style from that child component I just want to scope that change under that component.

The CSS I declare in Src/Style.css is:

```
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 24px;
}
```

and in my component I use following style in component css file :

```
::ng-deep .main-content {
  padding: 24px 0;
 }
```

At this moment, how can I alter the global styling from child component and scope that change only for that component.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `!important` property on your component's css file, that will overrite the global one.

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question, by using ng-deep its already overriting global one but problem is I want to scope this overrite only for that component. Currently while this overrite is happening it also remain for rest of life of the application ( when I navigate to other component) until I do browser refresh.

Comment: btw I have also tried !important it did same. Do you meant use !important without ng-deep?